# iOS swift 3 Alerim core data customize FetchRequestController

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, alecrimcoredata

I'm using Alecrim CoreData in one of my project. All setup is ok but I have one problem when configure the `fetchedResultController` for my `tableView`. Basically what I have done is:

```
fileprivate private(set) lazy var fetchedResultsController: FetchRequestController<Movie> = {

        let query = self.persistentContainer!.viewContext.movies.orderBy(ascending: false, { $0.releaseDate })

        return query.toFetchRequestController()
    }()
```

My question is how can I customize the fetchRequestController? For example change `fetchBathSize`, `fetchlimit`, `fetchOffset`...?